# assinatura P7s com C#

Tags: c#, .net, segurança

Pessoal tenho um arquivo p7s que pode conter várias assinaturas digitais, consegui com a classe X509Certificate2 pegar a última assinatura que foi feita no arquivo, preciso pegar todas as assinaturas que tem no arquivo.
Obrigado